# Why while compiling java code through cmd it's written as filename.java and running the same file we omit filetype?

Tags: javac

While compiling java files through cmd (ie through javac command) it is written as filename.java but to run the same program we write filename and don't add the extension. Why is extension removed in java command or extension added in javac command ? Any specific reason.

Comment: the correct answer to this is: "who cares?" that is just the way it works, because it was designed this way.

Comment: "Normal" execution of Java code is through a packaged jar file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why so? are the numerous .war files out there not entitled to be called Java projects? or do you mean to say that if it's not packaged in a jar/war/ear file, it's not a valid java project?

Comment: @Stultuske Thats what i want to know, why is it designed this way ?

Comment: @Stultuske I mean that end users are not intended to execute raw class files in general. Your additional packaging formats only reinforce that point, which is another reinforcement of "because it was designed that way".

Comment: This is not a CMD question. What do you want from a Windows language person about the non windows Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling, you specify the name of one or more source files, thus the .java extension

When running you specify the class name of the main class, thus no extension.

The difference becomes even more apparent, when the class is in a package:

```
javac mypackage/MyClass.java
java mypackage.MyClass
```

Comment: Also `javac` handles multiple files, *.java etcetera. A bit comparable with the class path parameter of `java`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I think this might be the answer. Could you do me a favor and point me to a resource where can i get more information on this ?

Comment: The search keywords are `java tools`, and of course a must-read is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627. There is a plethora of small tools like javap for disassemby, and such.